# Python: regex elements match with List

Tags: python, regex

I have a list, I want to compare each element of list against a list of regex and then print only what is not found with regex.Regex are coming from a config file:

`exclude_reg_list= qa*,bar.*,qu*x`

Code:

```
import re
read_config1 = open("config.ini", "r")
for line1 in read_config1:
    if re.match("exclude_reg_list", line1):
         exc_reg_list = re.split("= |,", line1)
         l = exc_reg_list.pop(0)
         for item in exc_reg_list:
             print item
```

I am able to print  the regexs one by one, but how to compare regexs against the list.

Comment: I suspect these are wildcard patterns, not regex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **re** module, I am going to use **fnmatch** module since it looks like wildcard pattern matching.

Please check this link for more information on [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html).

Extending your code for desired output :

```
import fnmatch
exc_reg_list = []

#List of words for checking
check_word_list = ["qart","bar.txt","quit","quest","qudx"]

read_config1 = open("config.ini", "r")
for line1 in read_config1:
    if re.match("exclude_reg_list", line1):
        exc_reg_list = re.split("= |,", line1)

        #exclude_reg_list= qa*,bar.*,qu*x
        for word in check_word_list:
            found = 0
            for regex in exc_reg_list:
               if fnmatch.fnmatch(word,regex):
                    found = 1
            if found == 0:
                   print word
```

Output:

```
C:\Users>python main.py
quit
quest
```

Please let me know if it is helpful.